# Python: Catching the output from subprocess.call with stdout

Tags: python

So im trying to save the output from my `subprocess.call` but I keep getting the following error:
`AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'communicate'`

Code is as follows:

```
p2 = subprocess.call(['./test.out', 'new_file.mfj', 'delete1.out'], stdout = PIPE)
output = p2.communicate[0]
```

Comment: The answers which recommend `Popen` were basically correct in 2012 when this question was asked, but the modern correct answer is to use `subprocess.run`, or `subprocess.check_output` if you need a simple API and/or compatibility back to older Python versions.  [The `subprocess` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) spells this out, in the very first paragraph of the first section; *"The recommended approach to invoking subprocesses is to use the `run()` function for all use cases it can handle.*"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for `subprocess.Popen()` instead of `call()`.

You also need to change it to `p2.communicate()[0]`.

Comment: This was correct in 2012, but the recommended solution now is to avoid `Popen` unless your use case requires it.

Answer (score 4):

That's because `subprocess.call` returns an int:

```
subprocess.call(args, *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False)

    Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete, then return the returncode attribute.
```

It looks like you want [subprocess.Popen().](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html)

Here's a typical piece of code I have to do this:

```
p = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, bufsize=256*1024*1024)
output, errors = p.communicate()
if p.returncode:
    raise Exception(errors)
else:
    # Print stdout from cmd call
    print output
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use subprocess

```
    try:            
        subprocess.check_output(['./test.out', 'new_file.mfj', 'delete1.out'], shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as exception:
        print exception.output
```