# How to check output of a sub process but also hide it?

Tags: python, subprocess

Hello I am sure this has been answered before, but I cant find the correct search terms to find it.

I would like to run a command in a sub process and check the output, but I dont want to see it in the terminal window.

I want to check a file with `ffprobe` and return the response in a way where I can see...

```
if "video" in ffprobe_output:
    print ("True")
else:
    print ("False")
```

But while hiding it from printing in the console.

Comment: Use this as a template (it's for FFMPEG as well), just pipe out `stderr` as well: [Python capture subprocess output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36364956/python-capture-subprocess-output)

Comment: Thanks. I got it working