# Running RUST server using Python Subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to write a wrapper for RUST game server using python and starting it with subprocess, it works problem is console output is all over the window only top line gets updated on stdout.

I am not reading and printing stdout as for some reason program (RustDedicated) wont accept stdin to write console commands.

How can i run RustDedicated.exe inside the wrapper the way batch file does so console gets displayed correctly?

Expected console output: [image: output]
Console output i am getting: [image: output]

The code:

```
args = f'{server} -batchmode {serverConfig}'
subprocess.call(args, shell=False)
```

Note: **server** referrs to RustDedicated.exe's location, **args** are just additional server arguments.

Thanks in advance, also [developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Rust_Dedicated_Server](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Rust_Dedicated_Server)  not the programming language.

Comment: may I ask why unity tag?

Comment: RUST is based upon unity3d, i thought it way have something to do with it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python capture subprocess output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36364956/python-capture-subprocess-output)

Comment: rust programming language based in unity, which is a game engine? I dont think that makes any sense, does it?

Comment: @rustyBucketBay https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Rust_Dedicated_Server

Comment: @Peter Badida You didn't read my question, Application does not accept stdin thats the reason i am not using it.